# Vidstack Controls not auto hide in mobile screen

Tags: vidstack-player

The hide control does not work on the mobile screen, but it does on the computer screen. It auto-hide controls, but not on the mobile screen. How to make it work on the same?

```js
let player = ref(null);

function onControlsChange(event) {
const isVisible = event.detail;
if (isVisible) player.value.controls.hide();
}


\<media-player @controls-change="onControlsChange" ref="player"\>

pass the delay to the method
.hide(3000)
```